# the exact time of "evening" and "night"

Tags: word-usage, difference

I wonder what the exact times of the following words are: morning, noon, afternoon, evening, night, mid-night.

What's the difference between *at night* and *in the night*?

Answer (score 19):

The answer to this question will vary depending on the season, as the winter months have shorter days and the summer months have longer days. Furthermore, there is no standard set of times that are universally accepted That being said, here is my classification of times:

- Morning is from sunrise to 11:59 AM. Sunrise typically occurs around
  6 AM.
- Noon is at 12:00 PM.
- Afternoon is from 12:01 PM to around 5:00
  PM.
- Evening is from 5:01 PM to 8 PM, or around sunset.
- Night is from sunset to sunrise, so from 8:01 PM until 5:59 AM.

This is just a general outline - it's more common to categorize these times based upon one's activities. For example, we eat breakfast in the morning and dinner in the evening.

Comment: What about his second question? 'At night' or 'in the night', which is more appropriate?

Comment: When asking Google Assistant, "When does afternoon turn into evening?", it recites this answer.